# PreparedStatement and 'null' value in WHERE clause

Tags: jdbc

I am using PrepareStatement and BatchUpdate for executimg a UPDATE query. In for loop I create a Batch. At end of loop I execute batch.

Above logic works fine if SQL query used in PrepareStatement does not have null values in WHERE claues.

Update Statement fails if there is null value in WHERE clasue.

My code looks something like this,

```
connection = getConnection();

PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(
        "UPDATE TEST_TABLE SET Col1 = true WHERE Col2 = ? AND Col3 = ?");

for (Data aa : InComingData){
    if(null == aa.getCol2()){
        ps.setNull(1, java.sql.Types.INTEGER);
    }
    else {
        ps.setInteger(1,aa.getCol2())
    }

    if(null == aa.getCol3()) {
        ps.setNull(2, java.sql.Types.INTEGER);
    }
    else {
        ps.setInteger(2,aa.getCol3())

    }
    ps.addBatch();
}

ps.executeBatch();
connection.commit();
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

If you do not wish to generate SQL dynamically, you may use `NVL` on all the nullable columns in your `WHERE` clause to convert `null` into some value that the column will never contain; and while setting the bind variables in `Statement` just convert `null` to the same value used in `NVL` function. For example,

```
String sql = "UPDATE TEST_TABLE SET Col1 = true
              WHERE NVL(Col2, -1) = ? AND NVL(Col3, -1) = ?";
```

And in `Statement`:

```
ps.setInt(1, aa.getCol2() == null ? -1 : aa.getCol2().intValue());
ps.setInt(2, aa.getCol3() == null ? -1 : aa.getCol3().intValue());
```

Answer (score 2):

That's because in SQL, `something = null` is always false, even if `something` is null. To compare a column with null, you must use `where col2 is null`, instead of `where col2 = null`.

Comment: Thanks for respone. But what changes I should do to make it work?

Comment: Well, build your SQL query dynamically depending on the nullness of your arguments.

Answer (score 0):

try use :

```
PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(
        "SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE ((1=? and maybe_null is null) OR (2=? and maybe_null = ?))");
```

```
if (maybeNull == null){
    ps.setInt(1, 1); // active left
    ps.setInt(2, 1); // inactive right
    ps.setString(3, '');  // any val
}else{
    ps.setInt(1, 2); // inactive left
    ps.setInt(2, 2); // active right
    ps.setString(3, 'some_value');  // THE VAL
}
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**